# Commas with conjunctive adverbs

Tags: adverbs, adjuncts

Which is correct?

> Certainly that was a good thing.

or,

> Certainly, that was a good thing.

Comment: I think we need a bit more context. It seems to me they could be saying different things.

Answer (score 1):

"Was that a good thing or a bad thing?"

"Certainly, that was a good thing."

*but*

"Was this or that (or both) a good thing?"

Certainly that was a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the given example, I'd go with the first (comma-less) option almost always.

> Certainly that was a good thing.

I can't actually think of a time I'd use the comma.